# Does mounting a USB on Ubuntu Server use the actual PC's disk space?

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, mount

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question.

I want to connect a 1TB usb hard drive to my server and access its storage. My actual server only has a 256GB SSD, and the amount of space taken up on the external hard drive is about ~350GB. Does that mean if I try to mount it, it will overload the SSD by taking up all the remaining space?

If so, is it possible to access the hard drive *without* mounting it, so it takes up no actual space on my server?

Thanks

Comment: Mounting no, copying/moving data from USB to SSD maybe, depending on amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, of course not.

If this was the case, you'd never be able to mount volumes larger than the free space left on your root file system.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to be 100% before I went ahead.